Bearded man in a tower jail builds a flying machine
I remember having seen a movie in my childhood (90s) that stuck in my head with the following associations of a scene: 

color-movie, somewhere between 70s and 90s 
seems to be an eastern European movie, maybe Russian or Czech
a (bearded) man is somewhere jailed high in a tower
there is classical music playing
the man is planing and building , in a series of cuts, a mechanical flying machine similar in shape to the wings of bats like on da Vinci's notes. 
finally, the scene is culminating and the man escapes using his machine. 


no, i have no idea, but if his name was rasputin it would not be the famous rasputin from boney m.

Any chance it's the one in this answer? (Here's the clip)

Could it be Hudson Hawk from 1991?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudson_Hawk
At the beginning of the movie, there is a scene for about 5 minutes which is set in the past with Leonardo Da Vinci (who has a beard) testing his flying machine out on a peasant/helper.  He's in a tower and launches the peasant in the flying machine from the top of it.  Before doing this, he is also shown to be tinkering with various things (like the machine that transforms lead to gold) and looking at his notebook which could explain the planning and building you mentioned.
At the end of the movie, Hudson Hawk escapes from (I think) the same tower in the same flying machine.

This was my first thought, as well.
